# Треугольник и точка

Tags: c

Мне нужно решить задачу, в которой даны четыре точки с координатами, три из них являются вершинами треугольника. Требуется определить, находится ли точка внутри треугольника или нет. Подскажите идею. Желательно привести какой нибудь код.

Comment: Для треугольника ABC и точки D, если все три произведения ABxAD, BCxBD, CAxCD имеют одинаковый знак, то точка D находится внутри прямоугольника.

Comment: Приведите ему код:)

Comment: >Приведите ему код:)

Код векторного произведения? Думаю, формулы будет достаточно:

    p1 x p2 = x1 * y2 - x2 * y1 = -p2 x p1

Comment: Задача с сайта acmp.ru.

Answer (score 1):

Это скорее всего учебное задание.
[Держите ответ.](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/)